# MySQL syntax error with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to read a value off MySQL using JDBC in the column "has voted". The syntax is supposed to search another column called 'Username'(which is the primary key and is unique) and return the corresponding value for 'has voted'.
This is the code for the method followed by the error code(s).

```
    boolean hasVoted(int userid){
    String q = "SELECT has_voted from voters"+
                "WHERE Username ="+ "'" + userid +"'";
    try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","abhi", "abhi");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(q);
        if(r.next()){
            int b = r.getInt("has_voted");
            if(b==0){
                return(false);
            }
            else{
                return(true);
            }
        }
        return(false);

    }
    catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        return(false);

}
```

}

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='2'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
at DistrictDatabase.hasVoted(DistrictDatabase.java:242)
at DistrictDatabase.initDatabase(DistrictDatabase.java:64)
at Server.main(Server.java:46)
```

Comment: There is no space between the `voters` and `where`.  Add a space in front of the word ` where`, but inside your string.

Answer (score 0):

Add space between "voters" & "where" like this

```
 String q = "SELECT has_voted from voters"+
                " WHERE Username ="+ "'" + userid +"' ;";
```